# Вывод разных id одной записью

Tags: php, mysql

```
        структура базы 
        id   text
        1    запись 1
        2    запись 2
```

Идея в том, чтобы, допустим, с нескольких выводов разные id выводились, например:

```
    echo $row['text']; // запись 1
    echo $row['text']; // запись 2
```

цикл не подойдет, потому как надо эти записи выводить в разных местах.

Comment: А нельзя записи в цикле получить, занести в какую-либо переменную, а уже потом вставлять куда хотите, например, как `$recordList[XXX]['text']`?

Comment: Может и можно, знал, не создавал бы тему, есть какие-то соображение поподробней? Что под [XXX] подразумевается?

Comment: XXX - любое число.

А вопрос был чисто риторическим. Вы логику получения записей увязали с отображением этих записей. Поэтому я и говорю - записи получаете в одном месте, а выводите их в другом месте. Это два независимых процесса, не надо их смешивать.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM language";
 $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 $langs = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  
  $langs[]=$row;
  
 }
<?php foreach($langs as $lan): ?>

с этим можно что нить подобное получить?

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на второй аргумент метода

```
PDOStatement::fetch([
    int $fetch_style [,
    int $cursor_orientation = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT [,
    int $cursor_offset = 0 ]]
])
```

> Чтобы запросить прокручиваемый курсор для запроса PDOStatement, необходимо задать атрибут PDO::ATTR_CURSOR со значением PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL во время подготовки запроса методом PDO::prepare()

Благодаря `cursor_offset` и `CURSOR_SCROLL` можно получить произвольную запись из результата, причем неоднократно. Однако, далеко не все драйверы поддерживают такое поведение, поэтому полагаться на эту возможность или нет - решать вам.